# Difference between System.setProperty("user.timezone", "America/Chicago"); and TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"));

Tags: java, timezone

1. System.setProperty("user.timezone", "America/Chicago");
2. TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"));

What is the difference between the two? Which one is better/recommended for setting the timezone?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code, the difference is essentially about when the TimeZone default gets set -

In the first case the default takes effect when the first call to TimeZone class is made(essentially lazily) - say `TimeZone.getDefault()` , at this point the `TimeZone.setDefault` gets called, the `user.timezone` is looked up and the default is set.

In the second scenario, the default is set eagerly - when you explicitly call `TimeZone.setDefault`

I think that is the only difference, either one should in practice work fine.

**Update**
This is the code from `java.util.TimeZone` class

The very first call to TimeZone.getDefault() has this flow, which covers your first point.

```
TimeZone.getDefault()
    -> TimeZone.setDefaultZone() (lookup "user.timezone" , set class variable and return timezone)
          -> return defaulttimezone
```

Next time getDefault() is called, it just returns the class variable

In the case of TimeZone.setDefault(timeZone), the class level variable `defaultTimeZone` is being set:
`defaultTimeZone = zone;` and returned.

Comment: What code did you look at? I am looking at System.java and also TimeZone.java, but I can't follow what you say. Can you please expand?

Comment: Updated based on what I see in `java.util.TimeZone` class. This is based on JDK 1.7 source code

Comment: Thanks Biju. The code in TimeZone is not that easy to follow up, but I think I can follow what you are saying. You mentioned that there shouldn't be any (drastic) difference. I googled for a recommended way, but didn't find anything. Have you happened to see any Sun/Oracle recommended way of setting timezone at all?

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference should be that "user.timezone" property and TimeZone's default timezone are stored separately.

See Java SE 8 doc [TimeZone#getDefault](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault--), [TimeZone#setDefault](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault-java.util.TimeZone-).

The main point is that `TimeZone.getDefault` may use "user.timezone" property as it's initial value, but the value will be cached. That means following changes to "user.timezone" won't affect `TimeZone.getDefault`. And `TimeZone.setDefault` does not change "user.timezone" property.

If you are not sure which one your code or third party libraries depend on, you'd better set both:

```
System.setProperty("user.timezone", "America/Chicago");
TimeZone.setDefault(null); // or TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"));
```

Take [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) as an example, it depends on both "user.timezone" property and `TimeZone.getDefault`, and "user.timezone" take precedence. See [DateTiimeZone.getDefault](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/v2.9.9/src/main/java/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.java#L144):

```
try {
    String id = System.getProperty("user.timezone");
    if (id != null) {  // null check avoids stack overflow
        zone = forID(id);
    }
} catch (RuntimeException ex) {
    // ignored
}
if (zone == null) {
    zone = forTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
}
```